# Suppress command line but show credentials

Tags: powershell, command-line, exe, credentials

I want to suppress the login of the command line. And just want to see the credential window.
So far the script is working with this command

```
   Add-Type -Name win -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public 
   static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);' -Namespace native
   [native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]:: 
   GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle,0)
```

I have compiled the script to an exe and it works so far except that the credential window is suppressed instead of the command line login.

I have tried various solutions to solve the problem, but nothing worked.

Comment: The code sample doesn't make any sense with the question. What is it supposed to do and how is it supposed to be related for password prompting?

Comment: The code does the same as -Windowstyle hidden. My Script is a gui for Get-MessageTrackingLog and when you start the script you have to authenticate as administrator, because I connect to the exchange server.

Comment: Are you trying to hide some window? What would that be? Why not use the existing credential prompt that provides password masking as a built-in feature?

Comment: I will try to hide the command line window.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-Command "
$Cred = Get-Credential
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Cred.Username)
"' -WindowStyle Hidden
```

you're hiding the process window handle low level - since the credential window is a child of it that will cause it to disappear as well, launching powershell with a hidden window will not suppress additional/child windows however.

The above code will output the username in a messagebox popup without displaying the PS window.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, thanks for the help! I found another way the solve the problem. When I compile the .ps1 to .exe I can set the parameter -console and this is working.